# Syestem takes +33 seconds to shutdown

Tags: boot, shutdown, plymouth

It's almost a week I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.The first days shutdown time was about 4 seconds but now it's almost 2 days the shutdown takes more than 33 seconds!!!
**My systemd-analyze blame**:

```
7.503s dev-sda7.device
6.237s mysql.service
6.069s systemd-cryptsetup@cryptswap1.service
5.351s apache2.service
2.461s NetworkManager.service
2.402s squid.service
2.370s apparmor.service
2.289s accounts-daemon.service
2.187s ModemManager.service
1.962s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-8d9f2106\x2dfa5b\x2d4452\x2d92
1.921s gpu-manager.service
1.483s keyboard-setup.service
1.435s bluetooth.service
1.404s thermald.service
1.395s preload.service
1.203s rsyslog.service
1.156s grub-common.service
1.100s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
946ms systemd-logind.service
945ms avahi-daemon.service
944ms systemd-udevd.service
885ms udisks2.service
813ms irqbalance.service
```

**Note**:
There were some more items on the above list like `network-manager.service`,`network-manager-wait-online.servic`,etc that are removed now.
**What I have done**:

```
sudo systemctl disable cups-browsed.service
changing  the timeout of NetworkManager-wait-online.service to 1
changing  the timeout of mysql-community to 1
#DefaultTimeoutStartSec=5s
#DefaultTimeoutStopSec=5s
#ShutdownWatchdogSec=1min
```

**plymouth reboot screen**:
When I shutdown/restart the system I pressed F12 and I saw the `plymouth reboot screen` and here is a shot-screen:
[image]
But still the problem hasn't solved!!:(
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you're having a disk problem with your RAID, possibly on sda7. Do you have a swap file there? Do you have multiple swap partitions? Please describe your disk configuration. Do you know how to run fsck? Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema sorry for late answer ,I just picked up the # from `defaultTimeoutStartSec` and everything gone!!!when I rebooted my system the loading page doesnt dissapear forever!!I think there must be a way using the shell in recovery mode but dont know how to do it!!

Comment: Your reply is very confusing, and it didn't answer any of my questions. If you need help, please clarify. I thought the problem was long shutdown times. Is more going on now? Cheers, Al

Comment: At first it was only shutdown time but as a mistake,a few minutes ago  I removed # from first of those lines and now ubuntu loading page doesnt disappear...

Comment: Again you're not clear about what your problem is. Removed what line from what... a file? Which file? Word your comments in such a way that somebody else who's not familiar with your problem(s) can fully understand what you already think you understand. Cheers, Al

Comment: I'm really sorry sir.By mistake I removed those `#` from the first of lines `DefaultTimeoutStartSec` and `DefaultTimeoutStopSec` in `system.conf`.Is there any solution??

Comment: Where is this system.conf file? I don't recognize it. Please explain HOW you changed this file. Al

Comment: In terminal I typed `sudo gedit etc/path.../system.conf` and then I changed them accidently.(I dont have access to ubuntu right now because it doesnt come up and I dont remeber the full path to system.conf but it was in /etc).

Comment: It's going to be difficult for me to talk you through the steps required to fix your problem. Maybe somebody else can chime in. Cheers, Al

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I found the problem...!Squid3 had caused that problem and when I removed it the shutdown speed became normal.